# add fields to awk command if Category field is not unique

Tags: awk

I have a few `awk` commands that I run and I need to alter the first one but can not seem to get the syntax correct. Basically, the ids in `list` are used to search `$3` of `file` and if they match and the `Category` field `($10)` or `(NF-1)` = `reference standard` then the `GeneID` or `$2` and  `RNA` or `$6` is outputted to the `update` result. That works if there is only one `reference standard`, however in `LAMA4` there are two `reference standards` so I need to use the `reference standard` or `$10` that has the greatest `t#` or `$7` and greatest `p#` or `$9`. I can not seem to incorporate that into the `awk` below. I apologize for the long post just trying to include all the details.

**list**

```
TTR
LAMA4
DSP
```

**file**

```
#tax_id GeneID  Symbol  RSG LRG RNA t   Protein p   Category
9606    7276    TTR NG_009490.1 LRG_416 NM_000371.3 t1  NP_000362.1 p1  reference standard
9606    3910    LAMA4   NG_008209.1 LRG_433 NM_002290.4     NP_002281.3     aligned: Selected
9606    3910    LAMA4   NG_008209.1 LRG_433 NM_001105206.2      NP_001098676.2      aligned: Selected
9606    3910    LAMA4   NG_008209.1 LRG_433 NM_001105207.2      NP_001098677.2      aligned: Selected
9606    3910    LAMA4   NG_008209.1 LRG_433 NM_001105208.2      NP_001098678.1      aligned: Selected
9606    3910    LAMA4   NG_008209.1 LRG_433 NM_001105209.2      NP_001098679.1      aligned: Selected
9606    3910    LAMA4   NG_008209.1 LRG_433 NM_001105208.1  t1  NP_001098678.1  p1  reference standard
9606    3910    LAMA4   NG_008209.1 LRG_433 NM_002290.3 t2  NP_002281.2 p2  reference standard
9606    1832    DSP NG_008803.1 LRG_423 NM_004415.3     NP_004406.2     aligned: Selected
9606    1832    DSP NG_008803.1 LRG_423 NM_001008844.2      NP_001008844.1      aligned: Selected
9606    1832    DSP NG_008803.1 LRG_423 NM_001319034.1      NP_001305963.1      aligned: Selected
9606    1832    DSP NG_008803.1 LRG_423 NM_004415.2 t1  NP_004406.2 p1  reference standard
```

**awk**

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} $(NF-1)$NF=="referencestandard" && $3 in a{print $3, ($5~/^NM_/?$5:$6)}' list file > update
```

**current result**

```
TTR NM_000371.3
LAMA4 NM_001105208.1
LAMA4 NM_002290.3
DSP NM_004415.2
```

**desired result**

```
TTR NM_000371.3
LAMA4 NM_002290.3  (since `$10` ="reference standard" and `$7` ="t2" and `$9` ="p2", this is used)
DSP NM_004415.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very beautiful, but

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} 
     $(NF-1)$NF=="referencestandard" && $3 in a && $7>b[$3] && $9>c[$3]{d[$3]=$3 FS $6; b[$3]=$7; c[$3]=$9}
     END{for(key in d){print d[key]}}' list file
```

outputs:

```
TTR NM_000371.3
LAMA4 NM_002290.3
DSP NM_004415.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :).